# react react-router-dom not found page error with live url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**react-router-dom v6.4.3**

**npm v9.1.1**

**node v18.12.1**

I am currently working on a react project.

I set the path using react-router-dom, it worked local environment.

But, when I upload to the server build file, I get a 404 error.

Below is my code

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/index/Home';
import Aboutus from './pages/sitemap/Aboutus';
import Privacypolicy from './pages/sitemap/Privacypolicy';
import Terms from './pages/sitemap/Terms';
import Contactus from './pages/sitemap/Contactus';
import Advertising from './pages/sitemap/Advertising';
import NotFound from './pages/404/NotFound';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <NavBarElements />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/Company/AboutUs" element={<Aboutus />} errorElement={<NotFound />} />
        <Route path="/Company/TermsOfService" element={<Terms />} errorElement={<NotFound />} />
        <Route path="/Company/PrivacyPolicy" element={<Privacypolicy />} errorElement={<NotFound />} />
        <Route path="/Company/Advertising" element={<Advertising />} errorElement={<NotFound />} />
        <Route path="/Company/ContactUs" element={<Contactus />} errorElement={<NotFound />} />

      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>

  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```
<span className='footer-sitemap'>
  <a href='/Company/AboutUs' className='text-reset'>
   About Us
  </a>
</span>
<span className='footer-sitemap'>
  <a href='/Company/TermsOfService' className='text-reset'>
   Terms of Service
  </a>
</span>
<span className='footer-sitemap'>
  <a href='/Company/PrivacyPolicy' className='text-reset'>
   Privacy Policy
  </a>
</span>
<span className='footer-sitemap'>
  <a href='/Company/Advertising' className='text-reset'>
   Advertising
  </a>
</span>
<span className='footer-sitemap'>
  <a href='/Company/ContactUs' className='text-reset'>
   Contact Us
  </a>
</span>
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaKWD.png)

[index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCaVT.png)

[when i click about us](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwobM.png)

I don't understand...
I also added errorElement. It also not working...

Any solution for this?

I tried using  but it's showing same issue

Comment: At least a couple issues: (1) you are rendering raw anchor tags instead of RRD `Link` components, so each is a page request to the server, and (2) the server isn't configured to return the root index.html file for all page requests; it's unable to find a file in the `"/Company/X"` directory and returns a 404. Where are you deploying to and serving the app from? See the CRA [deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) docs for a general idea how this is resolved. The `errorElement` is only used within Data routers.

Comment: I published on AWS

Comment: I do not understand "the server isn't configured to return the root index.html file for all page requests;" could you please explain more detail? @drew-reese

Comment: That was about as much detail as I could provide since you didn't mention where you were deploying the app to. I also provided a link to (*hopefully*) relevant documentation. Does the [AWS s3](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#s3-and-cloudfront) section help?